# Java and portability: Fake the presence of JavaFX

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, portability

Am developing a Java software which should be used on a raspberry pi. Now the Raspi sadly doesn't officially support JavaFx anymore, even if one can add it manually.

My software is mostly usable without JFX too and is intended to disallow using certain functions when JFX is not available.

The problem however is that I get NoClassDefFoundError exceptions regarding JFX although no function is meant to be executed.

It hasn't been possible for me to narrow down exactly what line causes the  exception because it is not replicable on PC (only on the raspberry) and the given line and class is very confusing. The line definitely does not call anything JFX related but it uses a static call to class which does require JFX for other functions (not the one called).

I am assuming that the reason is already the "import" call or the fact that the return type of some functions (which are not called!) have JFX datatypes.

Does anyone have an idea how to circumvent this fairly big issue?
Huge thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. Why don't you just install the missing parts of JavaFX from the Gluon web-site? Here is a tutorial which explains the process: https://wimdeblauwe.wordpress.com/2017/08/26/using-javafx-on-raspberry-pi-3-with-gluon/

You may additionally have to install missing dirmngr

```
sudo apt-get install dirmngr --install-recommends
```

2. An alternative would be to install OpenJDK on your PC, which also does not contain JavaFX, and use that to narrow down your problems with running your app in a non-fx environment.